# What happens when a thread holding a lock with ReentrantReadWriteLock fails?

Tags: java, multithreading

If the thread holding a ReentrantReadWriteLock.writeLock() stops executing due to an uncaught exception, is the lock released, or is it held and all the other threads are now deadlocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that by "fail", you mean an uncaught exception propagates off the top of the Thread's `run` method, causing it to stop executing.

If the thread used `finally` blocks properly, then it will have unlocked the `writeLock` on its way back up the stack.

If the thread didn't call `unlock()`, however, it still holds that monitor even though it's not running any more - so yes, other threads will be deadlocked.

This is why it's critical important to acquire and release resources correctly.  And also a reason to stick with `synchronized` blocks unless/until you can establish that you need the functionality of specific locks - because they cannot fail to be released.  (In your case I'm sure you do need the separate read/write locks, I'm making a more general point here.)

Answer (score 0):

You must use a try-finally block when using "Explicit Lock", to release any lock that you acquired.

This is a key difference between using synchronized.